# How can I create subdomains for a headless Service in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I have a Service that is deployed as a StatefulSet in one Kubernetes cluster, and with static IPs in another cluster.

```
kind: StatefulSet
apiVersion: apps/v1
metadata:
  name: statefulset-name
spec:
  ...
```

I want to use the same host to access the service in both clusters. I also need to have one hostname per endpoint (e.g the pod and the static IP).

Given that I get `<pod>.<statefulset>.<namespace>` in the Kubernetes-native case, how can I expose my static IPs with the same hosts?

Answer (score 2):

A StatefulSet will eventually generate a Service for the Pod. Digging into the [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/da23196df6d519c657a27c68932c62aa35e87dc5/pkg/controller/util/endpoint/controller_utils.go#L162) I found that the pod `subdomain` will map to the address `hostname` in the Endpoints resource.

Assuming that you have 2 replicas in the first case and 2 static IPs in the second one, you need to create the Service and Endpoints as such:

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: same-as-statefulset
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
---
kind: Endpoints
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: same-as-statefulset
subsets:
  - addresses:
    - ip: 10.192.255.0
      hostname: same-as-pod-0
    - ip: 10.192.255.1
      hostname: same-as-pod-1
    ports:
    - port: 80
```